# Repairing corrupt MP4

Tags: video, mpeg4

I took a video from my Android phone (Sony Xperia P, if you need to know), and before I could stop recording it, the phone memory got full and the phone got hanged too. I rebooted the phone, the video was there, but I couldn't play it from any media player on Android. It's in `mp4 format`.

So I tried to open it on PC and Mac with different video player, like VLC, quick Time, Windows Media Player etc., but none of them can play it. I know that the video is corrupted, but I believe it's repairable, since it got more than a GB in size. Is there anything that I can try  to repair the video file? The video is really important.

Answer (score 33):

This is an old question, but I just ran into the same situation and I figured I would post the solution that worked for me.

When you see the message "moov atom not found", that typically means that whatever was creating the video was not able to write terminal metadata that contains information about things like the codecs used in the video and so forth.  Without this "moov atom", most players will reject the video.

If you have *another* video that was generated by the same device, you can use the [untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) program to generate a new moov atom that will in most cases render the file playable.

You will need to compile the `untrunc` program yourself.  I built it in an Ubuntu 12.04 docker container, and needed to install the following prerequisites to get it to build:

```
sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev \
  libavutil-dev libqt4-dev make g++ libz-dev
```

Comment: It supposedly it supports files bigger then 1GB. However my input was >1GB and the output was just below 1GB and missing the end. The following tool helped to restore more video: https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer

Comment: Your prerequisites lack something: On Ubuntu 20.04 I get `libqt4-dev` has no installation candidate.

Comment: But I used the docker container like described in their Readme now, and that worked fine!

Comment: Be advised that in case the original [ponchio/untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) doesn't work for you to also try the newer `logging` branch in that repository and also try this fork: [anthwlock/untrunc](https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc)

Comment: I had to install yasm as well in order to compile libavformat

Comment: I used the newer fork of untrunc at https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc -- ran it as docker. Had to build with ff3.3 and run with flag -s (see readme) and... it worked like magic!

Answer (score 24):

If you have ffmpeg, from the command-line you can try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

If the problem is just with the container, this will fix it.

If that doesn't work, please post the complete terminal message, as it could give a clue as to how to fix the file.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that video. I'll try your method tonight. Can you let me know of any link from where I can get to know how to install ffmpeg. They just give zip or tar archives. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Creator - Look [here](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), scroll down to 'Linux builds' or 'Windows builds' or 'OSX builds', depending on your OS.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is the error I am getting while using ffmpeg command - [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f88f9018e00] moov atom not found
input.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input

Comment: did you ever resolve this? getting the same problem. Think it was caused by more or less the same thing too

Comment: I got the same problem and the same output. I could resolve it with this: http://grauonline.de/cms2/?page_id=5 but you have to pay for it if you want the other half of the video. Is there any other software that somebody can suggest to fix my mp4 file?

Comment: Have you tried recover_mp4_to_h264? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202611/repairing-a-corrupt-mp4-video-file

Comment: As @noob said: it doesn't work.

Comment: see also: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/fix-bad-files-and-streams-with-ffmpeg-so-vlc-and-other-players-would-not-crash?newreg=d3469ba54b784618bdee40c015f75889

Comment: This worked for me on an .MP4 that for some reason disallowed seeking in the video player (Win10 Movies & TV).

Comment: I get this error on Ubuntu 20.04: `avconv: command not found`

Comment: @rubo77 You first have to install ffmpeg with `sudo apt install ffmpeg` (if it is Ubuntu) or see here (http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for other operating systems.

Comment: Ffmpeg is installed. The error is thrown by avconf