# How can I fix a (possibly corrupt?) mp4 file?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, vlc-media-player, mp4

I'm afraid I don't know (can someone help me diagnose?) whether this file is corrupt or not.  I'm just guessing.  I'm using Linux, Lubuntu 20.04LTS, and VLC v 3.0.9.2.

1. Unlike the other mp4 files in this folder, which have thumbnails, this one doesn't.  Just a generic "mp4" icon.
2. Instead of opening the file or playing it (which works fine on other files in the folder) VLC just opens to a playlist window with a yellow bar zinging around at the bottom, as if it's trying to load but can't.
3. When I ran ffmpeg to just copy the file to another filename, hoping that might help, ffmpeg gave a "Invalid data found when processing input" error.

Are there any other ways to recover the file?  I took it with a drone and suspect that the file was taken at the end, and I may have grabbed the drone, flipped it sideways to turn it off, and shut down the battery...possibly it's something to do with that process and the file ended abruptly?  The file is large, 500MB, so there's data there that (ideally) I'd love to look at.

Anyone have suggestions for the next steps?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll need a dedicated software for that. Google "mp4 repair". It might cost you a buck or so

Comment: see this: https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/free-methods-to-repair-corrupt-mp4-video-files/

Answer (score 2):

Since you have other videos from the same device that are valid, you can use `untrunc` to repair it.

Original (now defunct): github.com/ponchio/untrunc
Fork with Windows GUI: https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc/releases

---

If you don't have other valid videos available from this device, you can sometimes get lucky and simply convert the video to another container format to repair it: https://superuser.com/a/539083

Comment: ` you should never pay for software` is the best advice. It is the whole reason we use SO....

Comment: In case my edit doesn't get approved: the original untrunc by ponchio is depreciated and can't build due to the libav project which is a dependency, being abandoned. A fork using ffmpeg and providing a windows gui is available: https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc/releases

Comment: @Underlines thanks for the edit. This fork looks amazing.